# How to fix "Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE" error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\new-training-site\config\info.php on line 4;

Here is line 4:

```
$link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$_SESSION['MM_Username']' AND password='$_SESSION['MM_PASSWORD']'");
```

Comment: How about: `$link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "' AND password='" . $_SESSION['MM_PASSWORD'] . "'");` Some clear concatenation? Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). You should also be aware that pasting variables into queries can open up for SQL injection.

Comment: Here is `line 4`:

    $link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='.$_SESSION['MM_Username'].' AND password='.$_SESSION['MM_PASSWORD'].'");

Comment: @AmitThakur I think you didn't figured out how concatenation works yet!

Comment: Please use descriptive titles to help people help you.

Comment: the one who mixes external data with SQL query in a single string should be taught the hard way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$link = mysql_query(sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='%s' AND password='%s'", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['MM_Username']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['MM_PASSWORD']),
));
```

It will help you [to avoid sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). And please don't use `mysql_` functions as it were mentioned in comments

Answer (score 2):

```
$link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='{$_SESSION['MM_Username']}' AND password='{$_SESSION['MM_PASSWORD']}'");
```